# how to display the severals column from other table to join with a principal table using the app google app script?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets placed in google sheet.

I look like to create third sheet concerning the 2 sheets to join in function of the control : Col1 of sheet A= col1 of sheet B using query

For instance :
Sheet A :

A      B      C
RPSG    BDE  KKKKKK 
RPSG    FGU  RRRRRRR
RPGA01  TDH  ttttttt

Sheet B  as location

A      B      C

RPSG  France   Paris
RPGA01 France  Toulouse
RPGA02 France  Lille

I tested in first time . here I copied the sheet A in Sheet C
and then,to add severals columns of sheet B, I add a function :
Query ( SheetB!A1:C3;"SELECT * where SheetC!A='RPSG'";1)

It works well , here, it displays one line of sheet 2 in sheet 3

Result : sheet C

A      B      C            D      E       F

RPSG    BDE  KKKKKK         RPSG  France   Paris
RPSG    FGU  RRRRRRR
RPGA01  TDH  ttttttt

And now, I would want that  all of datas of sheet B attached with sheet A in function of the col1 of sheet A = Col1 of sheetB to display in sheet C

Result : sheet C

A      B      C            D      E       F

RPSG    BDE  KKKKKK         RPSG  France   Paris
RPSG    FGU  RRRRRRR        RPSG  France   Paris
RPGA01  TDH  ttttttt        RPGA01 France  Toulouse

I tried it
In Sheet C
the Function :
Query ( SheetB!A1:C3;"SELECT * where A = sheetB!$A$1$:$$A3";1)

It Does not work.

May you help me this correction please.

Thank you in advance

Bertrand

PS: I hope you understand this mail because, I didnot pass to drop and drag the screenshot for instances to give you. sorry....

Answer (score 0):

Bertrand,  I think I understand what you want.

Try this formula:

```
={SheetA!A1:C3,ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(SheetA!A1:A3,SheetB!$A$1:$C$3,{1,2,3},0))}
```

It first gets all of the data from Sheet A.  Then beside it, it puts the values from Sheet B, after a VLOOKUP of the club name.

If you don't want to repeat the club name twice, you might prefer this formula:

```
={SheetA!A1:C3,ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(SheetA!A1:A3,SheetB!$A$1:$C$3,{1,2,3},0))}
```

which only gets the city and country from Sheet B, for each row of Sheet A.

You can put a SORT around it all to get them in alphabetical order:

```
=SORT({SheetA!A1:C3,ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(SheetA!A1:A3,SheetB!$A$1:$C$3,{3,2},0))})
```

Let me know if I haven't understood your question.

This image shows the results of all three formulas.

[image]